# S3 Bucket Policy to Allow access to specific roles and restrict all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to restrict access to a S3 bucket to all roles except select few roles using S3 Bucket policy.but here while i am switching into my writer and reader role its access denied.

**Bucket Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::581262627839:role/Rk-S3-Reader-I-Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::rkimpdocs"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::581262627839:role/Rk-S3-Writer-I-Role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::rkimpdocs/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::rkimpdocs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::rkimpdocs/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "JD",
                        "devops"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**IAM Role Permission for writer role** (Rk-S3-Writer-I-Role)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::rkimpdocs"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::rkimpdocs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::rkimpdocs/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output :

Access denied on both bucket policy and switching into mention role. Any help / suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explicit Deny will override any Allow. In your policies, the Deny in the bucket policy is causing the access denied. To give access to specific IAM roles and denying others, you should use "NotPrincipal" element. Please refer this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/) which explains your exact use case.
Also, "aws:Tagkeys" condition is [not supported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_s3.html) in S3, so you have to omit that as well.

Comment: Thanks brother for  your valuable comment  help me to understand the concept of "NotPrincipal" element very well & also thanks a lot for pointing me for "aws:TagKeys now i am using s3:ExistingObjectTag keys :)